# Why am I getting an error for missing file apr_dbd_odbc* when using rpmbuild for apr-util-1.6.1.tar.bz2?

Tags: linux, build, redhat, rpm, rpmbuild

I'm on RHEL 7.8, with the latest rpm-build installed.  I've downloaded the official apr-util-1.6.1.tar.bz2.  I already built the RPM for apr (apr-1.7.0.tar.bz2) successfully.  When I run from /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES as root:

```
rpmbuild -bb apr-1.7.0.tar.bz2
```

It goes along fine for quite a while but then spits out the build error:

> RPM build errors:
> File not found by glob: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/apr-util-1.6.1-1.x86_64/usr/lib64/apr-util-1/apr_dbd_odbc*

Those files, indeed, are not there.  The dbd files in that location are mysql, pgsql, and sqlite3.  Is there somewhere I need to get those files?  Thanks in advance, security has put a due date of Thursday on this update.  Apparently, RHEL7 repo doesn't play nice with security scans so we have to build and maintain our own apache now.

Comment: Note that we couldn't find a db4-devel (prereq for apr-util) but did find and install libdb4-devel.  Seems a possible culprit to me...

Comment: I noticed that the files it's looking for are in the tar.bz2 file, so I tried copying them into the location it's looking for them.  Well, next time through, they aren't there again.  That's nuts, do I have to find the right time during the rpmbuild to put them there?  Ouch!

Comment: Putting them there ahead of time didn’t work, but if I put them in the folder once the rpmbuild was pretty far along, I got it to succeed.  That's pretty whacky, but it worked...

Comment: I can't help you with your actual problem, but FYI _never_ build RPMs as `root` - a simple misstep can wipe the entire machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I had to do.  Nuts, but it worked:

1. bunzip and untar the apr-util-1.6.1.tar.bz2 file in an alternate location
2. cd into that untar to apr-util-1.6.1/dbd with one shell
3. in another shell, cd /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES, and then run:  rpmbuild -tb apr-util-1.6.1.tar.bz2
4. When the rpmbuild gets to the section “======== drop table ========”, cp apr_dbd_odbc* /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/apr-util-1.6.1-1.x86_64/usr/lib64/apr-util-1/

And it succeeded...